# Using pyodbc&pandas to load a Table data to df

Tags: python, pandas

I'm connecting to a DB and can get all the tables from it. No errors
I wanted to find a table named "ToolHistory" and later some other tables and then use pandas DF and filter some rows from the table/tables.
Here is what I got so far:

```
conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=SomeServer.com,1433;DATABASE=QQS;UID=me;PWD=allgetlost')
cursor = conn.cursor()
for row in cursor.tables():
    print(f" >> {row.table_name}")
    sql_query = 'SELECT * FROM ToolHistory'
    df = pd.read_sql(sql_query, conn)
    # tb_one = row.table_name
    # if tb_one == 'ToolHistory' :
        # print('Found Table ->',tb_one)    
        #df = pd.read_sql_table('tb_one', conn)
        #df = pd.read_sql_table('tb_one', cursor)
```

I cannot pass the line after the

```
print(f" >> {row.table_name}")
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: show the output of `print(f" >> {row.table_name}")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out how to get data from a table. Here is the code:

```
sql_query = 'SELECT * FROM ToolHistory'
df = pd.read_sql(sql_query, conn)
print(df)
```